# Azure Devops Output Variable not being passed between stages

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to pass variables between stages.  I have read many documents on the proper syntax of how to pass variables between stages, but none of the syntax appears to work, in addition to multiple other attempts at trying to find the proper syntax. Below is my yml file and the output.

```
stages:
- stage: InitialStage
  jobs:
  - job: StandAlone
    displayName: Required Stand Alone Job
    pool: Releases
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes"
      name: bash_test

    - task: CmdLine@2
      name: output_test
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "$(bash_test.doThing)"

- stage: CheckStage
  dependsOn: InitialStage
  jobs:
  - job:
    displayName: CheckStageJob
    pool:
      name: Releases
    variables:
      test1: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.StandAlone.output['bash_test.doThing'] ]
      test2: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.output['StandAlone.bash_test.doThing'] ]
      test3: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.StandAlone.output['StandAlone.bash_test.doThing'] ]
      test4: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.output['bash_test.doThing'] ]
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      name: test
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "$(test1)"
          echo "$(test2)"
          echo "$(test3)"
          echo "$(test4)"
```

First Stage Output:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /opt/azagent01/_work/_temp/652819a6-cd0c-4e34-a2c3-2da1d3339ab1.sh

Yes


Finishing: output_test
```

Second Stage Output:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /opt/azagent01/_work/_temp/bc144287-815e-4450-92e2-250cbbb92785.sh






Finishing: test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have syntax error in defining your variables.

> At the job level, the format for referencing variables from a
> different stage is
> stageDependencies.STAGE.JOB.**outputs**['TASK.VARIABLE']

```
stages:
- stage: InitialStage
  jobs:
  - job: StandAlone
    displayName: Required Stand Alone Job
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes"
      name: bash_test

    - task: CmdLine@2
      name: output_test
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "$(bash_test.doThing)"

- stage: CheckStage
  dependsOn: InitialStage
  jobs:
  - job:
    displayName: CheckStageJob
    variables:
      test1: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.StandAlone.outputs['bash_test.doThing'] ]
      test2: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.outputs['StandAlone.bash_test.doThing'] ]
      test3: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.StandAlone.outputs['StandAlone.bash_test.doThing'] ]
      test4: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.outputs['bash_test.doThing'] ]

    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      name: test
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "$(test1)"
          echo "$(test2)"
          echo "$(test3)"
          echo "$(test4)"
```

Output:

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo "Yes"
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/f1a4da2e-b447-4e4a-a78a-6e39f2f5edeb.sh
Yes
Finishing: output_test


Generating script.

========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/4d29ffb1-ba1a-41d1-b3d7-e89351c03493.sh
Yes



Finishing: test
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very shortsighted of me to not see that.